# React JS and Google maps error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am using google maps within a React js app. when I include the google maps file,

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key"></script>
```

A few seconds later a google auth call is made and then it returns and I get :

```
    Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: url
[168]</warning(condition=false, format="Something is calling a R....me/react-legacyfactory")dev-script.js (line 32928)
Number(props="8080", context=undefined, updater=undefined)dev-script.js (line 18728)
_.Dk(a=Object { type="object"}, b="8080")common.js (line 17)
_.Bk(a="http://localhost:8080/app/dist/js/init.js", b=undefined)common.js (line 16)
DB.prototype.j()util.js (line 219)
js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD1oZ-Do7cZYvwYIRGkMI2qpVmv1Vw6AU8(a=Object { type="object"}, b=Object { type="object"})js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 133)
Xc/e<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 53)
_.Mc/<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 50)
Xc/</<(a=Object { type="object"})js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 53)
Rc.prototype.ib/</d[a]<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 104)
_.Mc/<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 50)
Rc.prototype.ib/</d[a]<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 104)
_.Mc/<()js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 50)
Rc.prototype.ib/<(e=Object { type="object"})js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 104)
Sc(a=Object { type="object"}, b=Object { type="object"})js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 52)
Rc.prototype.ib(a="util", b=Object { type="object"})js?v=3....1Vw6AU8 (line 104)
util.js()util.js (line 1)
```

The error goes away if I don't include the google maps file

Comment: the `<script maps>` is in your index file right? not inside a jsx file...

Comment: Yes, it is in an index file, not a jsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any code with `React.renderComponent(`? change it to `React.render(`

It is very strange... do you have any component that uses google.map if it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

It was a variable that I was using Number. Google maps uses it too. Caused conflicts.